# Do not expand matrices in Mathematica calculation

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, evaluation, output-formatting, variable-definitions

Here is an example of a problem I'm having. Consider that I have defined:

```
omega={{p[t]},{q[t]},{r[t]}}

x={{a},{b},{c}}

R={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,d}}
```

What I would like to do is the calculation:

```
h=(R.omega+x).x
```

**My problem**: the output I would like to get is:

```
h=R.omega.x+x.x
```

However, mathematica by default will expand everything and just give me the resulting scalar number - I do not want this. Using //HoldForm will give me just:

```
h=(R.omega+x).x
```

Which does not help either. So how do I get the output h=R.omega.x+x.x where the expression is *expanded* but the variables are *retained*, i.e. *not* expanded themselves?

Thanks a lot! I appreciate it.

Comment: If you only want the expanded expression, why do you need to `Set` your variables to begin with? Simply do `h = Distribute[(R.omega + x).x]` before the three lines where you `Set` them to be matrices... Then you can of course use @march's method to replace them _a posteriori_ if you want.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer because eventually I want to switch between the developed version (where the R, omega and x get substituted with what they really are) and the undeveloped version. What you suggest is a stupid constraint to put on a user, there must be a way.

Comment: Would you like to accept one of the answers below (even if it's your own)? That way, we can remove it from the unanswered list.

Comment: @march Done, thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There will be more clever answers from people who better understand Mathematica's order of evaluation and how to use `Hold` and such, and so I can't answer your question in exactly the way that you've phrased it, but here's how I go about doing these types of things.

First, instead of declaring the values of `x`, `omega`, and `R` as you've done, make a list of rules:

```
Clear[x, omega, R]
rules = {omega -> {p[t], q[t], r[t]
  , x -> {a, b, c}
  , R -> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, d}}
 }
```

Then, your expression `(R.omega+x).x` evaluates to itself, because, as shown in the documentation,

> When its arguments are not lists or sparse arrays, Dot remains unevaluated.

Therefore, we have to tell Mathematica to distribute the `Dot` through the parantheses:

```
h = Distribute[(R.omega+x).x]
```

results in

```
R.omega.x + x.x
```

Now, to replace these quantities with your defined quantities above, merely do

```
h /. rules
```

resulting in

```
a^2 + b^2 + c^2
  + a (p[t] + 2 q[t] + 3 r[t])
  + b (4 p[t] + 5 q[t] + 6 r[t])
  + c (7 p[t] + 8 q[t] + d r[t])
```

#### Aside on notation

Typically, you want to define both "row vectors" and "column vectors" the same in mathematica, i.e.

```
rowVector = {a, b, c}
columnVector = {d, e, f}
```

The `Dot` operation will understand what you want:

```
rowVector.columVector
```

results in

```
a*b + b*e + d*f
```

Of course, this is also the result of

```
columnVector.rowVector
```

so if you're interested in doing other operations, you have to use something other than `Dot`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Inactivate` with `TraditionalForm`.

```
Inactivate[h = (R.omega + x).x] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

`Inactivate` prevents the operations from executing and  `TraditionalForm` gives the formatted output.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I like march's idea of automation but I think at the moment his updated code is not working.
Perhaps this will serve the purpose:

```
SetAttributes[heldDistribute, HoldFirst]
heldDistribute[expr_] := 
  Unevaluated[expr] /. 
    Cases[Unevaluated[expr], x_Symbol :> (HoldPattern[x] :> Defer[x]), {-1}, 
      Heads -> False] // Distribute
```

Now with the question definitions in place:

```
heldDistribute[(R.omega + x).x]
```

> ```
> x.x + R.omega.x
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies, they will be useful in the future. I found the solution to my specific problem however. One can use:

```
Distribute[(HoldForm[R].HoldForm[omega]+HoldForm[x]).HoldForm[x]]
```

Albeit cumbersome, it does the trick. To avoid it one can use @march or @MariusLadegårdMeyer solutions! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a completely different take (from my other answer, which I think justifies a separate answer) that somewhat automates the idea of using `HoldForm` on the variables. It works as long as you name the variables consistently. It's still not perfect, since, you need to make the `List` of `replacements`, but once that's done, you don't need to do the cumbersome thing of adding `HoldForm` to each `Symbol` in each expression that you create.

```
replacements = {HoldPattern[R] -> HoldForm[R], HoldPattern[x] -> HoldForm[x], HoldPattern[omega] -> HoldForm[omega]}
SetAttributes[heldDistribute, HoldFirst]
heldDistribute[expr_] := Distribute@ReleaseHold[Hold[expr] /. replacements]
```

Then

```
heldDistribute[(R.omega + x).x]
```

results in

```
x.x + R.omega.x
```

Comment: Your updated version does not appear to work properly, and I cannot see how it would without additional measures of expression holding.  I think you should check it again.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. You're right. I tested it with the symbols undefined. I will roll back the changes until I have a working version (although since you have a version, I am unlikely to work on this much; we'll see). Thanks for the heads-up.